# Can Outlook 2007/2010 be configured to not warn me if the subject is blank?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, microsoft-outlook-2010

Can Outlook 2007/2010 be configured to not warn me if the subject is blank?  I want to disable the prompt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Open Outlook
2. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F11</kbd>. This will open Visual Basic editor.
3. Expand the Project1 from Left side project pane
4. Expand Microsoft Office Outlook Objects
5. Now you will see "ThisOutlookSession". Double click on that.
6. Now copy following code and paste the below code in the new window opened when you double click on "ThisOutlookSession".

   ```
   Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean) 
   Dim strSubject As String 
   strSubject = Item.Subject 
   If Len(strSubject) = 0 Then 
   Prompt$ = "Mail is without subject. Do you want send it anyway?" 
   If MsgBox(Prompt$, vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbMsgBoxSetForeground, "Subject is empty") = vbNo Then 
   Cancel = True 
   End If 
   End If 
   End Sub
   ```
7. Save and Close the window. That is all.

Now you can try to send a mail without subject from your Outlook — you will get this wonderful alert.

Comment: My outlook 2010 *is* prompting.  I want it to not prompt.

Answer (score 1):

There's no GUI option and nothing in the published Group Policy settings, so "no" would appear to be the answer

Answer (score 1):

There's a tool called ReliefJet Essentials which does this.  The feature is called "Disable or Enable Warnings" and is at http://www.reliefjet.com/Product/Features/OutlookTweaks#TweakUI.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing an option like that in my Outlook 2007. Are you using it in an Exchange envrionment? If you are this may be being configured by the administrator.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get warnings when sending an email with a blank subject in Outlook 2007 or 2010. These warnings are probably because of a Macro. Go to tools > Macro > Macros and see if you have anything in there that looks for a blank subject on send.

The default config for Outlook definitely allows blank subjects.

Comment: Hi I'm not seeing that option at all.

Comment: @Matt - are you using 2007 or 2010. It may be located differently in 2010, I''ll have to check when I get to work tomorrow.

Comment: I have Outlook 2010 with a "default config" and no macros, and I do get warnings if I try and send an email with no subject, asking if I want to "send anyway" or "don't send". As far as I recall, it has been doing this since Technical Preview, Beta and now in RTM.

Answer (score 0):

If you press Alt+F11 in Outlook, it opens up the Macro editor. You may be able to delete the offending macro here. See this blog post:

http://lika.be/wp/2007/03/outlook-email-blank-subject-warning/

Comment: I don't believe it is a macro doing this. I get the same behaviour and I definitely have no macros added to Outlook.